# Preferable Bulk API Data Load Jobs monitoring options other than UI

Tags: api, bulk, event-monitoring, monitoring

This is clear that execution of Bulk API Data Load Jobs can be monitored from UI `Monitor Bulk Data Load Jobs` page. Besides of that, what are the other preferable options for Bulk API Data Load Jobs execution monitoring?

Is there any standard event Bulk API Status Event like `BatchApexErrorEvent` to subscribe via Trigger or Streaming API to status of Bulk API Job or any failures?

Should the debug logs level be set to finest and Id of running user be added to debug logs to monitor the jobs using apex console?

Should subsequent calls to REST resource `'/services/async/51.0/job/' + jobId + '/batch/' + batchId` be made?

Should the `getBatchInfo` method used in integration middleware application to monitor the status of the jobs from it?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to UI page monitoring, I think the best options are

1. Subsequent querying of REST resource `'/services/async/51.0/job/' + jobId + '/batch/' + batchId`
2. Subsequent calls of `getBatchInfo` method from middleware integration application if such is written or used.

I guess the option to monitor the jobs using apex console debug log is possible, but not very practical, since sometimes this is hard to catch the desired log and when there are a lot of logs, Apex console hangs.

As of Spring'21, there is no standard event firing from Bulk API execution process similar to `BatchApexErrorEvent`.